# convert time (without date) to Matplotlib num with date2num()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe df like this:

[image]

```
        datetime          duration
0   2018-10-08 13:30:00    03:00
1   2018-10-08 16:40:00    00:11
2   2018-10-08 21:30:00    03:19
3   2018-10-09 03:21:00    04:27
4   2018-10-09 07:49:00    02:11
```

both types of two columns are pandas.core.series.Series as:

```
In[20]:  type(df_sleep['datetime'])
Out[20]: pandas.core.series.Series

In[21]:  type(df_sleep['duration'])
Out[20]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

And I want to use the following to convert the data:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
dates.date2num(df_sleep['datetime'])
dates.date2num(df_sleep['duration'])
```

while the column 'datetime' works, the 'duration' column shows the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3720cbfdbdfa> in <module>()
----> 1 dates.date2num(df_sleep['duration'])

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in date2num(d)
    450         if not d.size:
    451             return d
--> 452         return _to_ordinalf_np_vectorized(d)
    453 
    454 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2753             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   2754 
-> 2755         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   2756 
   2757     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2823             res = func()
   2824         else:
-> 2825             ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   2826 
   2827             # Convert args to object arrays first

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   2783 
   2784             inputs = [arg.flat[0] for arg in args]
-> 2785             outputs = func(*inputs)
   2786 
   2787             # Performance note: profiling indicates that -- for simple

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in _to_ordinalf(dt)
    253         tzi = UTC
    254 
--> 255     base = float(dt.toordinal())
    256 
    257     # If it's sufficiently datetime-like, it will have a `date()` method

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

Anyone has any idea? my final goal is to plot the data in "datetime"(x axis)-"duration"(y axis) using Matplotlib.I guess it is because the column df['duration'] contains only time but not date, and not able to do conversion? How should I do to do the plotting?

thanks so much for any suggestion!

Comment: Please - no images of code, data or error messages or whatever. And where is your code? "function dates.date2num" might tell me, that you imported matplotlib.dates, but noone here wants to play guessing games... Please post your code as text, nicely formatted as code (select and then Ctrl+k) and the same with your data.

Comment: Hi @SpghttCd sorry for the mess of the question, I have edit it and makes it easily to understand. Thanks so much for pointing this out.

Comment: My first hint would be: do not ask for the type of a column of a dataframe - it's always a series. The interesting type is the type of the elements of a column, i.e. the output of `type(df_sleep['datetime']`[0])`. I'd guess that in datetime there are datetime values, but in duration there are strings.

Comment: What's your duration mean? it's HH:MM or MM:SS?

Comment: @SpghttCd thanks so much, I am still so raw for this. really appreciate your help, save me a looooot of time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess your duration format is %H:%M. first of all, change your column format to datetime.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, date2num

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df["duration"] = pd.to_datetime(df["duration"],format="%H:%M")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

myFmt = DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

ax.plot(df['datetime'], df['duration'])

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]